Playing a random sound in Pygame Zero on mouse click
I would like a game that I am coding to play a random 'success' noise when the user gets the correct answer. I cannot get pygame zero to do this elegantly (my code at the moment is long-winded)
It feels like this should be possible by calling a random list element, or randomising the string for the sound file. I have tried creating a list of the sound files and selecting a random element but pygame zero doesn't like this. I have also tried the simple solution at the bottom of this question, below.
The following does work, but I would like a more elegant way of coding this:
if index == question[5]:
                print("You got it right!")
                score += 1
                print("Questions answered: " + str(question_count+1))
                rand_sound = randint(1,12)
                if rand_sound == 1:
                    sounds.yes1.play()
                elif rand_sound == 2:
                    sounds.yes2.play()
                elif rand_sound == 3:
                    sounds.yes3.play()
                elif rand_sound == 4:
                    sounds.yes4.play()
                elif rand_sound == 5:
                    sounds.yes5.play()
                elif rand_sound == 6:
                    sounds.yes6.play()
                elif rand_sound == 7:
                    sounds.yes7.play()
                elif rand_sound == 8:
                    sounds.yes8.play()
                elif rand_sound == 9:
                    sounds.yes9.play()
                elif rand_sound == 10:
                    sounds.yes10.play()
                elif rand_sound == 11:
                    sounds.yes11.play()
                elif rand_sound == 12:
                    sounds.yes12.play()

Whereas the following does not work (I get the error message "AttributeError: No sound found like 'rand_sound'. Are you sure the sound exists?")
rand_sound = "yes" + str(randint(1,12))
sounds.rand_sound.play()


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

It's not in the official documentation, but you can use the sounds.load(name) method to get a sound object by passing the name as a string. (The same method is used by the Actor class to load an image).
Here's a minimal example:
import pgzrun
import random

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    sound_name = "yes" + str(random.randint(1,3))
    sounds.load(sound_name).play()

pgzrun.go()

